# Change SharePoint domain office 365 account

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm a new developer at a company. The company I work at provides each developer with a MSDN account with various included subscriptions. I recently activated my Office365 subscription and thought to create my own SharePoint public facing domain where I can go ahead and develop and test various things for myself in my own time.

Problem is, I'm not really sure how it happened but the domain ended up like this:

```
nameofcompany.sharepoint.com
```

or the public facing domain:

```
nameofcompany-public.sharepoint.com
```

I cannot use such a domain for my own personal testing and development. I haven't been able to find a way to change or remove this domain in my Office365 account. Is there a way I can do this? The Office365 account will be active for the period of one year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the url for public site collection, such as 'nameofcompany-public.sharepoint.com, but you can change the urls of the private site collections.

To change the url of the public site collection, when you select the public site collection in the SharePoint admin portal, the 'Rename Website' button will be enabled, click the button and follow the steps, then you can change the domain.

Comment: In order for me to rename the public site, I will first have to buy a new domain? I was hoping to change the default domain that was created when I registered the new Office365 account. It does seem that this is not completely possible..

Comment: @user3531031 yes, you have to buy one new domain